# "to take the plane often" vs "to travel by plane often" vs "to fly often"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have just heard a British person say:

> We often take the plane. (without any complement)

Does "to take the plane" mean "to travel by plane", "to fly" in this context? Is the first expression equally usual in both US and UK? I have only heard it with a complement, eg "We took a plane to Paris" or "We took the fastest plane of the company".

Comment: This can mean  the same as "to travel by plane" but can sound as though a specific plane is being mentioned.   Most Americans would say "We often fly."

Comment: I think most British people would too, but expressions like _take the plane, take the bus_ are perfectly understandable (=choose that mode of transport).

Comment: Thanks for making it clear! Could one of you please write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"We often fly" is more commonly used when speaking of air travel, but expressions like "take the train" and "take the bus", meaning "choose that mode of transport", are standard English.

Comment: If you fly frequently to a place, take the plane would be fine. Though "We often fly" is more common, yes.

Comment: @Lambie I didn't say it wasn't fine; I was elaborating on my previous comment in an answer as requested by the OP.

Comment: Nor did I say it wasn't fine.